# Dilation convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Below is a question, which I asked before, from Stein's Real Analysis.  I've provided a partial solution, which I think it's pretty along the lines of what needs to be done, however, I have no finished the solution.  If anyone has a hint for the part I'm stuck at, I would very much appreciate it. :)

Question:  Prove that if $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\delta > 0$, then $f(\delta x)$ converges to $f(x)$ in $L^1$-norm as $\delta \to 1$.

My Attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and suppose $\delta > 1$ (if not, just take $1/\delta$ in place of $\delta$). Since $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, there exists a function $g$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$ supported on a compact set $k$, with $\|f(x)-g(x)\| < \epsilon/3$.  Applying the triangle inequality, one finds that 
$$
\|f(\delta x) - f(x)\| \leq \|f(\delta x) - g(\delta x)\| + \|f(x) - g(x)\| + \|g(\delta x) - g(x)\|.
$$
With the assumptions on $f$ and $g$, together with the observation that 
$$
\|(f-g)(\delta x)\| = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |(f-g)(\delta x)| dx = \frac{1}{\delta^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |(f-g)(x)| dx = \frac{1}{\delta^d} \|(f-g)(x)\|
$$
one can estimate $\|(f(\delta x) - f(x)\|$ by 
$$
\|f(\delta x) - f(x)\| < \frac{2 \epsilon}{3} + \|g(\delta x) - g(x)\|.
$$
To complete the proof, it remains only to show that 
$$
\|g(\delta x) - g(x)\| \to 0 \quad \text{ as } \quad \delta \to 1.
$$

Observe that the function $g(\delta x)$ is supported on the set $\delta K$, a compact set; hence, the difference function $g(\delta x) - g(x)$ is supported on the compact set $\delta K \cup K$. Since $g(\delta x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\delta K$ and since $g(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, there exist positive constants $L$ and $M$, with $|g(\delta x)| \leq L$ And $|g(x)| \leq M$; hence writing, 
$$
\delta K \cup K = (\delta K \Delta K) \cup (\delta K \cap K),
$$
a disjoint union, where $\delta K \Delta K = (\delta K \setminus K) \cup (K \setminus \delta K)$, and applying the triangle inequality, it follows that 
$$
\|g(\delta x) - g(x)\| \leq \int_{\delta K \Delta K} |g(\delta x)| dx + \int_{\delta K \Delta K} |g(x)| dx + \int_{\delta K \cap K} |g(\delta x) - g(x)| dx.
$$
Using the definition of the Lebesgue integral, one then finds that 
$$
\|g(\delta x) - g(x)\| \leq 2(L+M) m(\delta K \Delta K) +  \int_{\delta K \cap K} |g(\delta x) - g(x)| dx.
$$
Now, if ${c_n}$ is any sequences of positive numbers such that $\delta = c_1 \geq c_2 \geq \dots$ and $c_n \geq 1$ for all $n$, decreasing to $1$, then the corresponding sequences of compact set $K_n = c_n K \Delta K$ decreases to the empty set, that is, 
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n = \emptyset.
$$
Moreover, since $m(K_1)$ has finite measure, by the continuity of Lebesgue measure, it follows that $m(K_n) \to 0$ as $c_n \to 1$. Hence, there exists $N \geq 1$ with $m(\delta K \Delta K) < \epsilon/12(L+M)$ whenever $n \geq n$ and $\delta \in (c_n, 1]$. 
Thus, 
$$
\|f(\delta x)- f(x)\| < \frac{2\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{6} + \int_{\delta K \cap K} |g(\delta x) -g(x)|dx
$$
whenever $\delta$ is sufficiently close to $1$.

Note:  The issue I'm having is dealing with the final integral $\int_{\delta K \cap K} |g(\delta x)-g(x)| dx$.  Any hints would be appreciated. : )

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence thm?

Comment: Yes, I do actually. I didn't think to even think that way here, since I was working with a dense subset of $L^1$.

Comment: That's probably the easiest way to proceed, since $\|f-f(\delta\cdot)\|\leq2\|f\|$.

Comment: I think I understand. I'll write an amendment after my note I left to see if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, the best way to solve this problem is probably using the dominated convergence theorem. But I'll address your actual question which was to show
$$\int_K|g(\delta x)-g(x)|dx\to0$$
as $\delta\to1$ where $K$ is compact and $g\in L^1$. What you should observe is that by density of $C$ in $L^1$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $g_\epsilon\in C\cap L^1$ such that $\|g-g_\epsilon\|<\epsilon$. Thus
$$\int_K|g(\delta x)-g(x)|dx\leq\int_K|g(\delta x)-g_\epsilon(\delta x)|dx+\int_K|g_\epsilon(\delta x)-g_\epsilon(x)|dx+\int_K|g_\epsilon(x)-g(x)|dx\\
\leq 2\|g-g_\epsilon\|+\int_K|g_\epsilon(\delta x)-g_\epsilon(x)|dx.$$
Taking $\delta\to1$ makes the second term zero since $g$ is continuous*, and taking $\epsilon\to0$ makes the first term vanish by assumption.

*note that making this line precise is where you require compactness of $K$.